# strange variable in lambda in foreach loop

Tags: .net

> **Please refer to question** [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-captured-variable-in-loop)

I want to ask why does the variable behaves strange?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        List<Action> lst_WANT = new List<Action>();

        foreach (var currNum in numbers)
        {

            //--------- STRANGE PART -------------
            int holder = currNum;

            lst_WANT.Add(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(holder);
            });
        }

        foreach (var want in lst_WANT)
            want();

        Console.WriteLine("================================================");

        List<Action> lst_DONT_WANT = new List<Action>();

        foreach (var currNum in numbers)
        {
            lst_DONT_WANT.Add(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(currNum);
            });
        }

        foreach (var dont_want in lst_DONT_WANT)
            dont_want();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The final output is:

1

2

3

--

3

3

3

Comment: The close votes for "not a real question" are not valid. However, this is very likely a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Captured Variable In Loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/c-captured-variable-in-loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your lambda expressions are sharing the same `currNum` variable.
After the loop finishes, that variable is `3`.

By using a separate variable declared inside the loop, you're forcing each lambda expression to use its own variable that doesn't change.

[Eric Lippert explains this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).